# How would one factor $9x^3 - 18x^2 -4x + 8$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been stuck on this for ages it just makes no sense to me. I have tried pulling out a greatest common factor but there isn't one. Not only this, but factoring by grouping doesn't seem to work either. This problem should be solvable without resulting to synthetic division or finding rational zeroes however I am stumped.

Comment: Nevermind, I am very stupid I realized I tried to factor out a 3 at the beginning rather than a 9 sorry.

Comment: Try $x=2$ .....

Comment: You can delete this question if need be it is an insult to my eyes at this point

Comment: @spacecadetMJ  We all have eye insults floating about the exchange.  It's good for us.  Mathematicians are arrogant enough as it is.  It's nice to be reminded that we're human.

Comment: I cheated with an online graphing calculator [to find the root $x=2$]. ((blushes))

Answer (score 2):

By checking the factors of $8$, we find that $f(2) = 0$. This implies that the polynomial is divisible by $(x-2)$. From then on, a simple use of the quadratic formula will suffice.

Comment: You were *lucky* in this case that it had an integer root. Checking only the factors of $8=f(0)$ does not generally suffice. Rather we need to check all rationals $\,a/b\,$ where $\,a\mid 8,\ b\mid 9\,$  by the Rational Root Test.

Comment: True. I generally check the integer divisors first, though. It generally suffices for situations where one expects "pretty" (i.e. integral) roots.

Answer (score 2):

Observe $$\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\begin{align}9x^3 - 18x^2 -4x + 8 &= 9x^2(x - 2) - 4(x - 2) \tag{Factor by Grouping}\\ &= (9x^2 - 4)(x-2)\\ &= (3x - 2)(3x + 2)(x-2) = 0 \tag{Difference of Squares}\\ \implies x&=\pm{2\over3},2.\end{align}$$

Comment: Special case of the Lemma in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the rational root theorem and you will get that the roots of the polynomial are $\pm\frac23$ and $2$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ By below $\,f(x)\,=\, \overbrace{8 -4x \color{#0a0}{-18}x^2+\color{#0a0}9x^3}^{\large 8/(-4)\ =\ \color{#c00}{{\bf -}2}\ =\ \color{#0a0}{(-18)/9 }} \,$ has root $\,x = \color{#c00}2\,$

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\,f(x)\, =\, \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} c_{\large k} x^{\large k}\, $ has *constant* $\,\color{#c00}{c_{\large 2k}/c_{\large 2k+1} = r}\,$  then $\,f(-r) = 0$

**Proof** $\qquad\! f(-r)\, =\, \sum_{k=0}^n\ (\color{#c00}{c_{\large 2k}-c_{\large 2k+1}r})(-r)^{\large 2k} = 0$

**Alternatively**, $ $ we can  $ $ *explicitly* $ $ factor out $\ r+x\ $ from successive terms as follows

$\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\, (\color{#c00}{c_{\large 2k}}\!+c_{\large 2k+1}x)x^{2k}\! = \sum _{k=0}^n \color{#c00}{c_{\large 2k+1}}(\color{#c00}r+x)x^{2k} = (r\!+\!x) \sum_{k=0}^n c_{\large 2k+1} x^{\large 2k}$

Methods like the above are sometimes called "factoring by grouping" or similar.